# Approximate sum of exponentials with single exponential

Tags: calculus, approximation

Let $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ be constants. Let $u_1,u_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be vectors.

Consider the function $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
h(x) = c_1 \exp ( \langle u_1,x \rangle) + c_2 \exp( \langle u_2,x \rangle)
$$

I would like to approximate this function with 
$$
g(x) = c \exp ( \langle u,x \rangle) 
$$
with $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is there an easy way to find the, in some appropriate sense, optimal choice of $c$ and $u$?

Edit: Furthermore, say I am particularly interested in the approximation on some region, $A$ to the extent I do not care about $A^c$ whatsoever (an example is $A= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : h(x)>0 \}$) is this possible to take into account?

Comment: When you are summing two exponentials, the one with higher order will dominate. Corrective factors can then be added, e.g by Taylor Expanding the lower order exponential

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks for the reply, that was very helpful and is in accordance with my intuition, I'm struggling a bit with the actual calculations though, would you mind elaborating? -maybe as an answer I can then accept :)